# How to bind jQuery event when ASP.NET MVC renders Model

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, rendering

I have following HTML code under Requisition.cshtml

```
    foreach (var item in Model.RequisitionWorks)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio"><label name="@string.Format("Option_{0}", item.OptionNumber)">@item.OptionNumber</label></div></td>
           <td>
               <div class="radio">
                  <label>@Html.RadioButton(string.Format("Option_{0}", @item.OptionNumber), 
"0", @item.IsOptionChecked("0"), new { @class = "OptionClass", id = string.Format("Option_None_{0}", @item.ToothNumber) }) @MyModelEntities.Properties.Resource.None
    </label>
  </div>
</td>
```

And I generate lots of radiobuttons...

So I would like to bind some jQuery event at the moment of rendering that code.

```
  $("#Option_None_" + optionNumber).change(function () {
  });
```

I need it because I generate **id** of html tag on fly.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not apply using the class of the option instead of an id?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".OptionClass").change(function () {
   });
});
```

Comment: I would like to use generated on fly ID of radiobutton and don't use the CLASS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the .on jquery method (http://api.jquery.com/on/). To accomplish this you would select your containing div and then set the onchange for the inputs within it.

```
$('div.radio').on('change', 'input', function() {});
```

Edit: it's a lot easier to do what you want to if you give the radio buttons a common class and use the above method. Generally it's not necessary use something unique like the id to attach the same event handler to each one.

Comment: I would like to use generated on fly ID of radiobutton and don't use the CLASS.

Comment: Why not use the class? If you need to see what was selected you can always look at the properties of the selected input via `$(this)` inside the function.